# BinaryFormatter No map for object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deserialization, binaryformatter

I'm serialized my object and put it in Resources folder in unity.
My game should copy this file into `Application.persistentDataPath` path and Deserialize. There i'm gettimg errror: `Failed to serialize. Reason: No map for object '201326592'.`

My "copy" code:

```
public void CopyAndDeserialize()
{
    saveData.itemsOfClothing = new List<ItemsOfClothingData.ItemOfClothing>();
    TextAsset resourcesTextData = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("items");

    path = Path.Combine(StorageManager.Instance.GlobalPath + _saveFileName);

    if(!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path);
    }

    File.WriteAllText(path, resourcesTextData.text);

    DeserializeData();
}
```

DeserializeData:

```
public void DeserializeData()
{
    path = Path.Combine(StorageManager.Instance.GlobalPath + _saveFileName);

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try
        {
            saveData = (ItemsOfClothingData)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to write it with a binary formatted. You can’t just write a load of text to a file and then expect it to be in format

Comment: You should wrap steams in a `using() { }` block rather than manually calling `Close()`.

Comment: ...also it would be better to pass `path` to  `DeserializeData` as an argument rather than attempt to reconstruct the path.  The latter is not the source of truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem.
Use `Resource.Load<TextAsset>(path).bytes` to get byte array and do deserialize like normal.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not a binary format, use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(string filepath)` or `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string filepath)` to read it properly.

See the Microsoft documentation for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-6.0